# Underline below the name of CTab

Tags: java, tabs, swt, ctabitem

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VdtE.png)
I am using Java SWT, and i have created a dialog box to take input from the user.

Inside the dialog box i have created two tabs using "CTabItem".

So initially when i open the dialog box the first tab is opened and by default an underline is coming below the name of tab .|

If i select somewhere else then the underline disappears and never comes back even though i tap on the tab name.

Why is the underline occurring at first time.
How can resolve this behavior.

Comment: Please add a related code, so that someone can help you in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

That line is shown if you create a CTabFolder but have not set the selected tab item and the control does not have focus.

To stop it appearing you need to set the selected tab item when you create the folder.

Something like:

```
folder.setSelection(0);
```

where `folder` is your `CTabFolder`

Comment: it is still coming when dialog box is opened until i select something else
Have attached the screenshot

Comment: This works for me, you will have to post a [mre] showing the problem.